# Apache POI - is there a way to create pivot table on SXSSFSheet?

Tags: apache-poi, pivot-table

Tried writing large dataset to excel, and able to do that well with `SXSSFWorkbook` instead of `xssfworkbook`.

Now I am trying to create a pivot table with the already-written large dataset as base data. Unfortunately, `SXSSFSheet` does not have `createPivotTable`: only XSSFSheet has that facility.

Is there anyway I can use `SXSSFSheet` to create pivot tables?

Comment: SXSSF has to sacrifice various things in order to hit the very-low memory footprint. Sadly you can't both have your cake and eat it too....

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I use SXSSFWorkbook to create a large .xlsx with pivot in few sheet.

So I create these sheet with below code. And make sure your source table is also XSSFSheet or it will cause some error. (Sheet not related to the pivot could be Sheet/SXSSFSheet is fine)

Hope this solution could help you to resolve your question.

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getXSSFWorkbook().createSheet("Pivot sheet");
AreaReference ar = new AreaReference("A1:" + "AI" + (source.getLastRowNum() + 1));
CellReference cr = new CellReference("A1");
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(ar, cr, source);
```

Comment: "source" does not necessarily need to be an "XSSFSheet" - but when an "SXSSFSheet" is used, make sure the first row of the "AreaReference" is in the SXSSFWorkbook's row access window to avoid a NullPointerException somewhere down the createPivotTable->createCacheFields call stack.